# how to force MS Word to continue text in the first column

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an MS word document in a 2 columns layout. I have to write a long equation that must span the two columns.

I select the equation, then: **Layout** > **Columns** > **One**.

The problem is that the text immediately before the equation continues in the second right column (See the Yellow text in the image below).

What I want really is to force the yellow text to continue in the **left** column, not in the right one.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could put the text in a two-column table, then make the row containing the equation to span the two columns.

Comment: I'm not sure it it's possible since I don't work with equations, but can you put the equation in a box that spans both columns. If you use text wrap, it will cause the text to not run underneath the box

Comment: Just put the formula in a text box and wrap the text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text box that spans the columns.  Use "top/bottom" wrapping.  Then, copy/paste the equation into the text box.  Let us know if that works.